# Wordpress pagination stay on the same page

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, wordpress

Hi I am currently working on a website and I have created a template to where I am going to sell items I want to show 10 items and then go to the next page. However pagination does not work. when i click older entries, in the url it shows paged 2 but the content is the same! how can i fix this? below is my code.

```
<div id="shop_header"><h1>OUR SHOP</h1></div>

<div id="items_details" class="wrap clearfix">



<?php
```

$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
query_posts('cat=2&posts_per_page='.get_option('posts_per_page').'&paged=' . $paged);
?>

```
    <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

    <div <?php post_class() ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" >

    <article>

    <div class="item">

            <div id="item_header" class="clearfix">
                <h2 class="item_head"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>

            </div>  

            <div class="img">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
            </div>



            <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>

            <div id="social_posts" class="clearfix">

            <ul>

            <li id="like"></li>
            <li id="comment"><?php comments_popup_link('0', ' 1 ', '%'); ?></li>

            </ul>

            </div>


            <button class="clearfix"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Buy Now</a></button>

    </div>      
    </article>
```

```
    <h2>Not Found</h2>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Why are you rebuilding the wheels? Just curious, because there are bunch of wordpress plugins that does pagination. wp-pagenavi perhaps. https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-pagenavi/

Comment: Are you doing it in a Custom Page Template? Why don't you just use a Category or a Custom Taxonomy? Are you using a plugin for the e-commerce part or is all your code? Where are the navigation links or the navigation function in your code?

Comment: no this is all my code i havent used any eCommerce plugins and yes it is a custom template. if possible could you explain what custom taxonomy is? this is supposed to be like a sort of a blog page. the way i wanna display my items is the same as posts

Comment: I also did try wp-pagenavi for some reason it does not work